# How do I stop websites, opened in firefox, such as YouTube and Amazon from appearing seperately as an app on the launcher or dash?

Tags: launcher, unity-dash

This just creates unnecessary clutter on my launcher.

Comment: I think you can click "Do not ask again" and it will not ask you again if you want to install the webapp.

Answer (score 1):

These are called the Unity Webapps. If you want to stop them from showing up in the Launcher, you'll have to uninstall or disable them. The easiest way is to disable them.

To disable the Unity Webapps in Firefox: open Firefox, go to **Tools > Add-ons** (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), click on **Extensions**, and disable **Unity Desktop Integration**. I'm not sure if you'll need to restart Firefox, but do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Unity Tweak Tool, found in the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Then go to Web Apps and then turn off the WebApps integration.

For the latest version of [Unity Tweak Tool](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/unity-tweak-tool-available-in-ubuntu.html) you can install it from its PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```